# Pulling JS vars from Bootstrap table using Form without AJAX. Better way?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, html-table

I wrapped a Bootstrap (BST) table with a Form element. The BST populates the table data with a json file automatically in Javascript on client side, and the table and form look like this:

```
<form id="info" role="form" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table data-toggle="table" 
           data-url="tables/sharedMem/jsonTickerList"  
           data-show-refresh="true" 
           data-show-toggle="true" 
           data-show-columns="true" 
           data-search="true" 
           data-select-item-name="toolbar1" 
           data-pagination="true" 
           data-sort-name="name" 
           data-sort-order="desc" 
           data-page-size="15" 
           data-single-select="true" 
           id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="state" data-radio="true" >Report ID</th>
                <th data-field="cik" data-sortable="true">CIK</th>
                <th data-field="ticker"  data-sortable="true">Ticker</th>
                <th data-field="company" data-sortable="true">Name</th>                 
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small" name = "button">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

As you can see, the BST DOES NOT define the table rows or TD's on the server side (because its client side JS enabled).  So the only way to capture data that I can find to return row data with the click of a submit button in the form is:

```
$(function () {   
    $('#events-table').next().click(function () {
        $(this).hide(); 

        var $result = $('#result');

        $('#table').bootstrapTable({})
            .on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
                $result.text('Event: click-row.bs.table, data: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
                var url = "confirm.php?cik=" + row.cik;
                document.getElementById("info").setAttribute('action', url);
            });
    });
});
```

The two lines above work fantastic. They make it all work.
My problem is that the BST code has a message element needed. It looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="result" ></div>
```

When this alert is in the code, the table will not send events to the alert object unless I click the alert first, then click the row in the table. Without the alert in the code, I can't get anything to work. Once I do the preemptive click everything works great, but that is weird. I hope someone can see what is wrong. I'm just too lame with Javascript.. I would hope I could just load the page, click a row, and the JS updates the action attribute in the form element so that when I click the submit button then all is ok.

The BST is great! I can load 10000 records into the table from /dev/shm in about 100 milliseconds and its search feature just is screaming fast so I hope to just debug this last bit so it's a smoother customer experience.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the problem and found a solution. The correct javascript now is:

```
    $(function () {   
    $('#events-table').click(function () {

    $('#table').bootstrapTable({})
        .on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        var url = "confirm.php?cik=" + row.cik;
        document.getElementById("info").setAttribute('action', url);
        });
    });
    });
```

the HTML:

```
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="result" > </div>
```

is completely deleted too. Net result is when the table loads, it is fully navigable via pages or search. clicking a row, (or radio button with a minor change) captures the row data so that when you click the Form Submit button, the form data created using client side javascript and json is passed into php's $_POST in the normal way.

I just tested the table with 1.1 million records (3 fields each). It loads in under a second and you can navigate to the last row in 1/2 second. While thats on a 1 Gb intranet, and the data file is 77MB on the test, I think it shows the BST is pretty cool, looks fantastic, and is pretty fast when you store the large json file on /dev/shm, too. All the Form and BST html mentioned previously is correct.

Key to this was removing the "next()" method in the JS since it was effectively ignoring the first click on the table row that I wanted to select. I just guessed that JS would accept ".click" instead...that turned out correct...after a fair number of trial and error mistakes.